# Run kube-proxy on fedora server 23 panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: kubernetes

fedora :

```
[root@host3 vagrant]# cat /etc/os-release
NAME=Fedora
VERSION="23 (Twenty Three)"
ID=fedora
VERSION_ID=23
PRETTY_NAME="Fedora 23 (Twenty Three)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;34"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:23"
HOME_URL="https://fedoraproject.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Fedora"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=23
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Fedora"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=23
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL=https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Legal:PrivacyPolicy
```

kube-proxy version:

```
[root@host3 vagrant]# kube-proxy --version=true
Kubernetes v1.1.2
```

Run command and error msg:

```
[root@host3 vagrant]# kube-proxy --logtostderr=true --v=0 --master=http://host1:8080 --proxy-mode=userspace --cleanup-iptables=true
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0xb1 pc=0x465e26]

goroutine 1 [running]:
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kube-proxy/app.(*ProxyServer).Run(0xc2080d79d0, 0xc208046af0, 0x0, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0)
```

/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kube-proxy/app/server.go:309 +0x56
    main.main()
/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kube-proxy/proxy.go:53 +0x225

```
goroutine 7 [chan receive]:
github.com/golang/glog.(*loggingT).flushDaemon(0x12169e0)
```

/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/golang/glog/glog.go:879 +0x78
    created by github.com/golang/glog.init·1
/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/golang/glog/glog.go:410 +0x2a7

```
goroutine 17 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/src/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2232 +0x1

goroutine 15 [chan receive]:
github.com/godbus/dbus.(*Conn).outWorker(0xc2080daa20)
```

/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/godbus/dbus/conn.go:367 +0x58
    created by github.com/godbus/dbus.(*Conn).Auth
/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/godbus/dbus/auth.go:119 +0xea1

```
goroutine 12 [sleep]:
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util.Until(0xda66f0, 0x12a05f200, 0xc20800a7e0)
```

/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/util.go:127 +0x98
    created by k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util.InitLogs
/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/logs.go:49 +0xab

```
goroutine 14 [IO wait]:
net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0xc2080d6920, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/src/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:84 +0x47
net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead(0xc2080d6920, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/src/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:89 +0x43
net.(*netFD).readMsg(0xc2080d68c0, 0xc2080e28c0, 0x10, 0x10, 0xc20816d220, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0xffffffffffffffff, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /usr/src/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:296 +0x54e
net.(*UnixConn).ReadMsgUnix(0xc20803a0f0, 0xc2080e28c0, 0x10, 0x10, 0xc20816d220, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0xc2080e276c, 0x4, ...)
    /usr/src/go/src/net/unixsock_posix.go:147 +0x167
github.com/godbus/dbus.(*oobReader).Read(0xc20816d200, 0xc2080e28c0, 0x10, 0x10, 0xc20816d200, 0x0, 0x0)
```

/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/godbus/dbus/transport_unix.go:21 +0xc5
    io.ReadAtLeast(0x7f7eeae0df58, 0xc20816d200, 0xc2080e28c0, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/src/go/src/io/io.go:298 +0xf1
    io.ReadFull(0x7f7eeae0df58, 0xc20816d200, 0xc2080e28c0, 0x10, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/src/go/src/io/io.go:316 +0x6d
    github.com/godbus/dbus.(*unixTransport).ReadMessage(0xc2081250d0, 0xc208112660, 0x0, 0x0)
/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/godbus/dbus/transport_unix.go:85 +0x1bf
    github.com/godbus/dbus.(*Conn).inWorker(0xc2080daa20)
/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/godbus/dbus/conn.go:241 +0x58
    created by github.com/godbus/dbus.(*Conn).Auth
/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/godbus/dbus/auth.go:118 +0xe84

```
goroutine 16 [runnable]:
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/iptables.(*runner).dbusSignalHandler(0xc2080d6850, 0x7f7eeae0e028, 0xc20803a100)
```

/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/iptables/iptables.go:525
    created by k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/iptables.(*runner).connectToFirewallD
/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/iptables/iptables.go:186 +0x7a7

anyone who can help me?

Comment: FWIW the --master flag is useless here :)  Also, there's a known issue in that this doesn't clean up all the rules when switching from iptables back to userspace mode.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug when using the `--cleanup-iptables=true` flag in the 1.1.2 release, as I can reproduce a panic when running on a GCE node. I've created [kubernetes#18197](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/18197) on your behalf and this bug will be fixed in the upcoming 1.1.3 release.